# Is there a Set datatype in VimScript?

Tags: vimscript, dictionary, list

I am aware of lists and dictionaries in Vim. But are sets supported in Vim to store only unique values? Or do I just have to use a dictionary with some dummy value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no datatype Set. So you have to implement it yourself or maybe find some implementation on the net.

If you implement it yourself, you might consider "Dictionary functions" (see `:help Dictionary-function`) or "numbered functions" (see `:help numbered-function`).

Here is a quick hack. Maybe you can start from this. Note: This "Set" can only handle strings or numbers.

```
function! NewSet()
    let newSet = {'dict': {} }

    " number of elements in set
    function! newSet.len()
        return len(self.dict)
    endfunction

    " adds element to set
    " returns 1 if element was added, 0 if it was already present
    function! newSet.add(element)
        if ! has_key(self.dict, a:element)
            let self.dict[a:element] = 1
            return 1
        else
            return 0
        endif
    endfunction

    " returns 1 if element is contained in set
    function! newSet.contains(element)
        return has_key(self.dict, a:element)
    endfunction

    " removes element from set
    " returns 1 if element was removed, 0 if it was not present
    function! newSet.remove(element)
        if(self.contains(a:element))
            call remove(self.dict, a:element)
            return 1
        else
            return 0
        endif
    endfunction

    " returns content as list
    function! newSet.as_list()
        return keys(self.dict)
    endfunction

    return newSet
endfunction

" TEST

let mySet = NewSet()

echo "Add Vim: " . mySet.add("Vim")
echo "Add Vim 2: " . mySet.add("Vim")

echo "Add NeoVim: " . mySet.add("NeoVim")

echo "Contains Vim: " . mySet.contains("Vim")
echo "Contains NeoVim: " . mySet.contains("NeoVim")
echo "Content: " . string(mySet.as_list())
echo "Len: " . string(mySet.len())
echo "Remove Vim: " . mySet.remove("Vim")
echo "Remove Vim 2: " . mySet.remove("Vim")
echo "Contains Vim: " . mySet.contains("Vim")
echo "Content: " . string(mySet.as_list())
echo "Len: " . string(mySet.len())
echo "Remove UNKNOWN: " . mySet.remove("UNKNOWN")
```

---

**Update**

I reconsidered my answer and came to the conclusion, that my previous example
implementation has a drawback. Whenever you create a new Set, the functions
are added as anonymous (aka numbered) functions. So if
you create two sets, all functions are parsed two times and defined two
times.

The better solution is to define the functions once and just add the
function-references to the Set implementation.

So I would recommend this updated implementation:

```
" number of elements in set
function! s:len() dict
    return len(self.dict)
endfunction

" adds element to set
" returns 1 if element was added, 0 if it was already present
function! s:add(element) dict
    if ! has_key(self.dict, a:element)
        let self.dict[a:element] = 1
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    endif
endfunction

" returns 1 if element is contained in set
function! s:contains(element) dict
    return has_key(self.dict, a:element)
endfunction

" removes element from set
" returns 1 if element was removed, 0 if it was not present
function! s:remove(element) dict
    if(self.contains(a:element))
        call remove(self.dict, a:element)
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    endif
endfunction

" returns content as list
function! s:as_list() dict
    return keys(self.dict)
endfunction

function! NewSet()
    let newSet = {'dict': {},
                \ 'len': function("s:len"),
                \ 'add': function("s:add"),
                \ 'contains': function("s:contains"),
                \ 'remove': function("s:remove"),
                \ 'as_list': function("s:as_list"),
                \ }
    return newSet
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

VimScript, like Perl, does not have a native `set` datatype.  (And like Perl, the keys of Vim's `dict`s are all strings.)  Decades ago, when I was learning Perl (and some Python) back in 2002, Python didn't have a native `set` datatype, either.

So what was a programmer supposed to do back then when a `set` datatype was needed?  As you asked here:

> do I just have to use a dictionary with some dummy value?

That's exactly what I was taught to do when I needed to use a logical set.  `set`s are essentially `dict`s with ignored values, and it follows that anything you can do with a `set`, you can also do with a `dict`.

I've written lots of code to emulate sets with Perl's `dict` datatype (which are called "hashes" in Perl).  While I do much prefer using a native `set` datatype when one is available (such as those found in Python and Ruby), in a pinch using a `dict` with dummy values to simulate a `set` works just fine.